# Are these both a correct way to find the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Are the green and yellow boxes both correct ways of finding the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix? And is there any difference between the two?

[image]

Comment: Yes. The formula with the green background is what is obtained withe the definition of an $n×n$ determinant as an $n$-linear alternate form that is equal to $1$ for the unit matrix. The formula with the yellow background is the expansion of the determinant along the $i$-th row (there is a similar formula for the expansion along a column).

Comment: Yes, they are both correct.  Which you take as the original definition is up to you, but I believe the Leibniz formula came first chronologically.  They can be shown to be equivalent.  The first is the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants).  The second is the [Laplace Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

Comment: As for "*is there a difference*" The final result will be the same.  One might require less arithmetic and effort than the other depending on the specific values.  It is useful to be familiar with both.  In my experience, it is not uncommon for undergraduates to have never even heard of the Leibniz formula, having exclusively used the Laplace version.